# IDE does not recognize inet_pton

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, clion

I am trying to write a simple-ish TCP client in C++. I was following [this guide](https://bitbucket.org/sloankelly/youtube-source-repository/src/8a4847e8ca5f9f039a7246a1172aa87f64ef55c5/cpp/networking/BarebonesClient/Barebones_Client/main.cpp?at=master) and this is the short code I have so far:

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "messenger.h"
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#endif
#include <winsock2.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    WSADATA d;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &d)) {
        perror("Failed to initialize.\n");
    }

    Messenger::connect();

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

`messenger.h':

```
class Messenger {
public:
    static void connect();
...
}
```

and `messenger.cpp`:

```
#include "messenger.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <wspiapi.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

#define IP "192.168.0.99"
#define PORT 3030

SOCKET prop_socket = INVALID_SOCKET;

std::thread Messenger::receive_thread;

void Messenger::connect() {
    setup();
    receive_thread = std::thread{listen_for_messages};
}


void PropulsionMessenger::setup() {

    std::string ipAddress = IP;

    sockaddr_in hint;
    ZeroMemory( &hint, sizeof(hint) );

    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

}

...
```

However CLion highlights `inet_pton` and tells me that `Use of undeclared identifier 'inet_pton'`. I believe all of the fields are filled with the correct data types and I have all of the required header files. I get no other errors.

Comment: You need to define `_WIN32_WINNT` everywhere before you include Windows headers. Best to put it in a header and include that everywhere you need to.

Comment: @RetiredNinja It worked thanks! By the way is the `_WIN32_WINNT` declaration that I have correct for a 64-bit Windows machine?

Comment: If `_WIN32_WINNT` isn't defined already, I rather recommend you add `_WIN32_WINNT` in your `CMakeLists.txt` file for your project.

Comment: Also, I just looked at the [official sample tcp client server code from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/finished-server-and-client-code) and thery did not include that definition at all, that's kind of weird, right?

Comment: @ACCazacu I usually add `_WIN32_WINNT` and similar macros as compilation command line defines as they set the version of the MS-Windows API used in the project, and you don't want different values in different files. See also [Using the Windows Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers)

Comment: @ACCazacu It's very likely set by the MSVC compiler. If you use CLion there's a possibility you use another compiler (GCC from MinGW perhaps?), where it's not defined.

Comment: @ACCazacu `inet_pton()` was introduced in Windows Vista, so `_WIN32_WINNT` (or more specifically, [`NTDDI_VERSION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff549459(v=vs.85))) must be set to VISTA or later in order to compile properly. Microsoft examples don't usually cover `_WIN32_WINNT` requirements.